# About layout in React Native

Tags: react-native

I used two `<View>`s to lay out this interface, and I rounded the borders of the `<View>`s in the following section. There is a problem here, the sides of the screen are not filled and there are gaps. How can I deal with this problem?

[image]

This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, Image, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Linking } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor="transparent" barStyle="light-content" />
        <View style={styles.titleBar}>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bodyContent}>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

//Stylesheets
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleBar: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#E9E9E9',
  },
  bodyContent: {
    flex: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
  },
});
```

Comment: can you please share the code. it would be better if you shared the code, it is easier to suggest a solution

Comment: I'v posted the code. :)

Comment: Can you mark the gaps in the screenshot?

Comment: It's between the grey and white blocks. A dark irregular shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting a background color on a parent view, something like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, Image, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Linking } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor="transparent" barStyle="light-content" />
        <View style={styles.titleBar}>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bodyBackground}>
          <View style={styles.bodyContent}>
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

//Stylesheets
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleBar: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#E9E9E9',
  },
  bodyBackground: {
    flex: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#E9E9E9',
  },
  bodyContent: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
  },
});
```